# How to refresh a Python import in a Jupyter Notebook cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two files:

MyModule.py
MyNotebook.ipynb

I am using Jupyter Notebook, latest, and Python, latest. I have two code cells in my Notebook.

**Cell #1**

```
import some stuff
Run some code
(Keep everything in the environment takes about five minutes to run this cell).
```

**Cell #2**

```
import MyModule
Execute code from MyModule
```

I would like to make code changes in MyModule.py and rerun **Cell #2** but without restarting the kernel (**Cell #1** did a fair amount of work which I don't want to rerun each time).
If I simply run the second cell, those changes made to MyModule.py do not propagate through. I did some digging, and I tried using importlib.reload. The actual code for **Cell #2** :

```
from Nash.IOEngineNash import *
import importlib
importlib.reload(Nash.IOEngineNash)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't quite working. How can I push those changes in MyModule.py (or Nash/IOEngineNash.py in actual fact) into my Notebook without restarting the kernel and running from scratch?

Comment: try reloading the entire `Nash` module. `import Nash as nash; from importlib reload reload; reload(nash)` . Further you can use the required `IOEngineNash`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Isn't "from Nash.IOEngineNash import *" reloading the entire module? I may be mistaken. Also, won't "import Nash" suffice rather than adding "as nash"? Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same issue , while importing a custom script , when used an alias for `import` , the `reload` worked

Comment: That's awesome. It worked. If you add that as an answer I can upvote etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I faced a similar issue , while importing a custom script in jupyter notebook

Try importing the module as an `alias` then reloading it

```
import Nash as nash
from importlib import reload
reload(nash)
```

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that all references to the old version of the module are updated, you might want to re-import it after reloading, e.g.

```py
import mymodule
reload(mymodule)
import mymodule
```

Issues may arise due to implicit dependencies, because `importlib.reload` only reloads the (top-level) module that you ask it to reload, not its submodules or external modules.

If you want to reload a module recursively, you might have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/KristianHolsheimer/f139646259056c1dffbf79169f84c5de), which allows you to simply add a line like this at the top of a notebook cell:

```py
%reload mymodule
import mymodule
```

This recursively reloads the `mymodule` **and** all of its submodules.